# Pass the browser to next test

Tags: user-interface, browser, coded-ui-tests, functional-testing, arquillian-drone

I'm trying out Arquillian Drone and Graphene this time with Groovy and I have the following 2 tests what i want to do is have the second test use the browser from the first tests. but the browser closes after the first test finishes - is there a way to pass the browser to the second test?

```
@RunWith(ArquillianSputnik)
@RunAsClient
@Stepwise
class testclass extends Specification {

@Drone
private WebDriver browser;

@Page
SubPage subPage

@ArquillianResource
URL url

def 'It should navigate to subscription page'() {
    when: 'I go to  subscription page'
    browser.get('http://localhost:8585/');

    then: 'It should should enter sub name'
    subPage.enterName("Name")
}

def "Enter subdescription"() {
    when: "I enter a sub description"

    sub.enterDescription('Description')

    then: "Subscription description should be visible in description input field"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

second test will look like

```
 def "Enter subdescription"() {
     when: "I enter a sub description"
     browser.getCurrentUrl()
     sub.enterDescription('Description')

     then: "Subscription description should be visible in description input field"

}
```